# International student on a scholarship terminating early - lease break problems

Tags: breaking-the-lease, students

So, I will be leaving 3 months earlier than planned, and I have teied to break my lease with the student housing complex agent, but had no luck. I left a deposit, so one month would be covered, but they expect me to pay for the remaining 2 even though I will leave the country. I don't have an SSN, but they do have my passport and scholarship ToA contract. My question is - what happens if I just leave? Can they sue me or contact the University/Scholarship Sponsors and how likely is it to happen for only 2 months? I wouldn't want to have anything on my name in case I ever want to visit US again

Comment: We cannot answer the "how likely" part. They might talk to the university to try and get further contact details, e.g. your address prior to the application. Even if the university is not *allowed* to release that information, the debt collectors may talk them into it. Much smarter to pay the remaining rent and to get a protocol in what state you left the apartment (things like stopping utilities).

Comment: You need q jurisdiction.

Answer (score 4):

Anybody who walks out on a lease obligation can be sued for the money that they owe. The only thing that leaving the country adds is complication over the landlord collecting. In principle, A can sue B regardless of the countries that they live in. The landlord would sue you in state court, then would seek enforcement in your country. If your country is North Korea, the North Korean courts may not recognize the US state court claim, but UK courts would because there is a treaty whereby we recognize the judgments of each other courts, at least in areas where our laws agree (i.e. if you walk out on a lease, you still owe the money).